# Multiple x variables in faceted boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Is it possible to use multiple x-variables for a faceted ggplot boxplot? I am using facets in ggplot to stratify my analysis but would like to have two different classifications of price on the x-axis depending on the colour (E or F). I've made a test example using the diamonds data set where I have two different price classifications but can only figure out how to apply one at a time:
[image: ExampleBoxPlot1-SinglexVar]
[image: ExampleBoxPlot2-SinglexVar]

But I'd like to have a plot that considers both price classifications, depending on colour:
[image: FakedGraph-BoxplotsWithMultiplexVars]

I know I could get a similar result using grobs and probably by assigning a the price category conditionally depending on the colour (E or F) but that seems a bit cumbersome. So for simplicity, I'd like to do this using facets. Is that possible, if so, how?

```
dat <- diamonds

# price grouping I
dat$priceI <- cut(diamonds$price,
                  breaks = c(0,5000,10000,Inf),
                  labels = c("0-4,999","5,000-9,999",">=10,000"),
                  right = FALSE)

# price grouping II
dat$priceII <- cut(diamonds$price,
                 breaks = c(0,1000,5000,10000,Inf),
                 labels = c("0-999", "1,000-4,999","5,000-9,999",">=10,000"),
                 right = FALSE)

ggplot(dat[(dat$color=="E" | dat$color=="F") & 
      (dat$cut=="Fair" | dat$cut=="Good"),],
      aes(priceI,depth)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_grid(cut ~ color) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Why is it cumbersome to assign it manually? You could make a priceIII with the conditional price category, and then facet the same way. Seems the simplest option to me.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in @Heroka In that case I find the graph shows all factor levels from both scales combined. Hiding unused factors might partially solve the problem but I do want to show empty categories if they show up...just not if they weren't part of the original categorization (e.g. above I'd want to hide an empty 1,000-4,999 category on the left side but not the right). In my final version the data will change monthly so empty categories may appear and I'd like to see those. Maybe two graphs put together using a grob is the only way to go?

Comment: I think in that case grobs are the way to go.